# Jquery Loop appending image element just appends once

Tags: jquery, loops, dom

I'm trying to append an image element multiple times trough a loop, but it is only appearing once, any idea why?

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = 'image.jpg';

    for(i=0; i < 12; i++) {
    $('#photos').append(myImage)
    }
});
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the image object within the `for` loop because if it is not then it is using the same object multiple times

[**See demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/6b2ojvdb/)

Change you jQuery to this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var myImage = new Image();
        myImage.src = 'image.jpg';

        $('#photos').append(myImage);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** This will not affect the page load time because the browser will load the image only once and cache it for further use. You can see more details here [When a page loads an image, does it load it only once, or every time it is found in the markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340376/when-a-page-loads-an-image-does-it-load-it-only-once-or-every-time-it-is-found)

Comment: The thing is I want the image to be loaded and ready to append before appending it, this wouldn't slow down that process?

Comment: @MarcoCastro are you going to append the image 12 times? Is this fixed or might change?

Comment: yes I will, it will change because they will be different images, regardless what I want is to have my images loaded before appending them, that's why I don't want them to be appended within the loop i don't know if it make sense what I am saying

Comment: @MarcoCastro it will not affect the page load time at all check my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

This is faster:

```
var i, images = '';

for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    images += '<img src="image.jpg">';

$('#photos').append(images);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method

```js
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = 'image.jpg';

    for(i=0; i < 12; i++) {
    $('#photos').append(myImage.cloneNode())
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="photos"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    for(i=0; i < 12; i++) {
       var myImage = new Image();
       myImage.src = 'image.jpg';
       $('#photos').append(myImage)
    }
});
```